# How do you write your own intellisense comments in a Javascript file?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In C# I can make comments that start /// before the definition of a class or function and these affect the intellisense tips shown when I write code that uses the type or function. But it isn't working in Javascript. Can I get these special comments and extra tips?

Comment: I think this is the relevant documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385682(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Not the far, but the comment should be in the js function.

Here is an exemple :

```
function getArea(radius)
  {
      /// <summary>Determines the area of a circle that has the specified radius parameter </summary>
      /// <param name="radius" type="Number">The radius of the circle.</param>
      /// <returns type="Number">The area.</returns>
      var areaVal;
      areaVal = Math.PI * radius * radius;
      return areaVal;
  }
```

You will also find [HowTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514138.aspx) and [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh524453.aspx) in MSDN.

Answer (score 3):

For VS 2017+ up to current date of this comment, you need to use JSDoc for TypeScript. `{string}` in this example means that param1 is of type string, where "*param1*" is the name of your parameter. `@param` is a necessary keyword to denote that what follows is the intellisense/JSDoc description of the parameter. You would add an "`@param`" for each additional parameter in its own line. The text "*The first argument to this function*" represents what you want intellisense/JSDoc to show as a description for the parameter.

```
/**
 * A description for myFunction.
 * @param {string} param1 - The first argument to this function
 */
function myFunction(param1) {
...
}
```

- [JSDoc ref](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html)
- [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/javascript-intellisense?view=vs-2022#:%7E:text=IntelliSense%20based%20on%20type%20inference.%20In%20JavaScript%2C%20most,initialize%20it%20or%20the%20most%20recent%20value%20assignment.)
- [JS for VS Wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JavaScript-Language-Service-in-Visual-Studio)